# How do I generate reports using RestAssured with cucumber

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured

I'm new to Cucumber and RestAssured framework.

I want to generate reports using RestAssured with cucumber in my project.

Please let me know if you need any more information on this regard.

Comment: Cucumber provides reporting options, or you can use it combined with other reporters. Which version of Cucumber are you using? How will you be running your cucumber tests? RestAssured would be used to implement step definitions, so it not directly relevant to the reporting.

Comment: Marit, Thanks for the reply. I have added Cucumber plugin in Eclipse. That version is "Cucumber Eclipse Plugin 0.0.20.201712221009". I will be running cucumber tests using Maven as "mvn clean install"

Comment: Yw. I don't use Eclipse so can't help you there. We run from the commandline or JUnit runner, in that case you can specify a plugin for reporting, not sure how to do it from Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestAssured does not provide you reporting options. However if you are using Maven then go for surefire plugin report (add it as dependency to your POM.xml) and it will help you pull in reports based on the junit tests that you run.

Else, Serenity framework combined with Rest Assured provides very detailed reports infact it logs all the requests and responses intuitively. This [guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/restful-api-testing-using-serenity-and-rest-assured-a-guide) will help integrating serenity with rest assured.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber of version 6.7.0 and above provides Cucumber Report Service. Follow below-mentioned steps:-

1. You need to add Cucumber-jvm of version 6.7.0 and above in your pom.xml.
2. You need to create a Cucumber.properties file in src/test/resources and mention this instruction in that cucumber.properties file - cucumber.publish.enabled=true. When you will run the cucumber tests from command line using mvn test, a cucumber report will be generated. To know the more details, can refer this [link](https://qaautomation.expert/2021/03/28/cucumber-report-service/)